# How many engineers do I have?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Is there a way to see how many engineers I have? I can see if I have enough available for a given project, but I can't find the total number (or even the total number available).

Knowing this would help me decide which abduction site to address.

Answer (score 16):

You can see it when you are in the engineering bay start screen or when you select items for manufacture, bottom mid:

[image]